# Add multiple items to shopping cart with AJAX, only one is processed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a shopping cart to which items are added with an AJAX request. The request posts to Laravel 5.4. It all works fine when I click multiple 'Add To Cart' buttons slowly after each other. Then the AJAX requests aren't executed at the same time. But when I click those buttons fast after each other, the AJAX requests are executed at the same time and only one item is added to the cart.

The jQuery:

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (event) {
    // Get the product/service ID.
    var item = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.post('/cart', {
        action: 'addItem',
        data: item
    }, 'json').done(function (response) {
        // Hide .add-to-cart and show .go-to-checkout
    });
});
```

The PHP:

```
public function addItem(Request $request)
{
    // Get item from request.
    $item = $request->get('data');

    // Store item in session.
    $request->session()->push('cart.items', [$item]);

    // Return JSON response.
    return response()->json([]);
}
```

When I use `async: false` in my AJAX request, all items are added to the cart, no matter how fast I add them. But because that option is deprecated, it doesn't feel right to use it. I've also looked at alternatives like Promises, but I don't know how to use them in my case.

I'm trying to figure out why only one item is being processed when multiple items are being added quickly after each other. Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: where are you setting the `item` variable in your js? It's possible you are sending multiple requests for the same `item` value. You can also try checking the Network tab in Chrome or Firefox dev tools to see exactly what request data you are sending

Comment: Forgot to put that in my example code, thanks for noticing. The 'item' variable is simply the ID of the product/service, nothing special. I've used the Networks tab in Chrome and saw that every request contained a different ID, like it should.

Comment: Is it really necessary to be able to add items fast? You could just disable the `.add-to-cart` buttons while a request is beeing processed.

Comment: I assume you have checked the network tab in dev tools to make sure your requests have been sent?

Comment: Take a look at this library: [laravel-locking-session](https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session). "It addresses the problem where session data is lost due to concurrent requests updating the session at the same time. One instance where this may happen is when making simultaneous XHR requests."

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette well I don't assume much customers will click the buttons that fast, so it's not that big of a deal, I just want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: @AdamForbis yes, I made sure of that. ;p Laravel gives the response I expect it to give.

Comment: @Hollings wauw, never thought of that. Just figured out that Laravel sessions are not exactly the same as standard PHP sessions. I'll look into that! Can you post your comment as an answer in the meantime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can use the `laravel-locking-session` library to keep Laravel from overwriting your session data. I haven't used it, but it claims to fix the exact problem you are experiencing.

https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its possible to collect items in js-code and then pass them to ajax.

The jQuery:

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (event) {
var items = {COLLECT_ITEMS_FUNCTION};
$.post('/cart', {
    action: 'addItems',
    data: items
}, 'json').done(function (response) {
    // Hide .add-to-cart and show .go-to-checkout
});});
```

The PHP:

```
public function addItems(Request $request) {
$items = $request->get('data');

foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Store item in session.
    $request->session()->push('cart.items', [$item]);
}

// Return JSON response.
return response()->json([]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel version 7+ is supporting Session blocking. The `block` method on the route is limit concurrent requests for a given session

```
Route::post('/cart', function () {
    //
})->block($lockSeconds = 10, $waitSeconds = 10)
```

https://laravel.com/docs/session#session-blocking